# Finite Difference Time Domain Method - approximating point out of grid?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

I'm just curious about the following
$\begin{align}
   H_z\big|_{i+1/2,j+1/2}^{n+1/2} =  H_z\big|_{i+1/2,j+1/2}^{n-1/2} + \frac{\Delta t}{\mu_{i+1/2,j+1/2}}\Bigg[ \frac{ E_x\big|_{i+1/2,j+1}^{n} -E_x\big|_{i+1/2,j}^{n} }{\Delta y} - \frac{ E_y\big|_{i+1,j+1/2}^{n} -E_y\big|_{i,j+1/2}^{n} }{\Delta x} \Bigg] \\\\
   E_x\big|_{i+1/2,j}^{n+1} =  E_x\big|_{i+1/2,j}^{n} + \frac{\Delta t}{\epsilon_{i+1/2,j} \Delta y}\Bigg[  H_z\big|_{i+1/2,j+1/2}^{n+1/2} -H_z\big|_{i+1/2,j-1/2}^{n+1/2} \Bigg] \\\\
    E_y\big|_{i,j+1/2}^{n+1} =  E_y\big|_{i,j+1/2}^{n} - \frac{\Delta t}{\epsilon_{i,j+1/2} \Delta x}\Bigg[  H_z\big|_{i+1/2,j+1/2}^{n+1/2} -H_z\big|_{i-1/2,j+1/2}^{n+1/2} \Bigg] 
   \end{align}$

I'm focusing on the last two finite difference updates. My question has to do for example the $E_x$ update. We observe that when $j=0$ then we need $H_z\big|_{i+1/2,-1/2}^{n+1/2}$, which is clearly outside the stencil. I'm curious how one goes about approximating it outside the domain? I have a similar issue obviously when $i=0$ with $E_y$.

Comment: First, it depends on what boundary conditions you are using. Some approaches include solving for the end point using your discretisation formula (Dirichlet) and the *ghost point method* (Neumann conditions), both of which you can Google to find literature and youtube videos where they discuss how to implement these methods (or go to scicomp.stackexchange and see questions there). See [here](https://www.math.uci.edu/~chenlong/226/FDM.pdf) under 'Boundary Conditions' for more help.

Comment: I have dirchlet boundary conditions. I agree when they are neumann, the ghost point is easy to use.  However with dirchlet where the value is specified on the boundary, how can we specify it outside i.e -1/2?